# Why component is called twice in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

This is my `pages/index.js` of my `next.js` project

```
const Index = () => {
  console.log('Index Component Called');
  return (
    <div>Hello</div>
  )
}

export default Index;
```

The console log function is called twice on **CLIENT** side and one time on next.js node **SERVER**

Answer (score 3):

I guess because `Pages` in `next.js` are server side rendered (or pre-rendered).
So in this case when next.js is rendering your page(server side), the script will `console.log("Index Component Called")` then on your frontend react  it's [hydrating](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate)  so  all the code coming from the server should be executed again.
In next.js you can execute  Server Side code inside `getInitialProps`, and in pages only not components.